# 2019 Moderator Election results (unofficial)

Tags: discussion, election

The official [2019 Community Moderator Election Results](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2624/2217)

---

Here is the result of running the ballot file in openSVT using the Meek SVT method:

> Loading ballots from file blender-stackexchange-com-2019-election-results.blt.
>   Ballot file contains 2 candidates and 185 ballots.
>   No candidates have withdrawn.
>   Ballot file contains 185 non-empty ballots.
>
> Counting votes for Blender Stack Exchange Moderator Election 2019 using Meek STV.
>   2 candidates running for 1 seat.
>
> ```
>  R|Duarte Farrajo|Pierre Schille|Exhausted     |Surplus       |Threshold     
>   |ta Ramos      |r             |              |              |              
> =============================================================================
>  1|    150.000000|     35.000000|      0.000000|     57.499999|     92.500001
>   |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
>   | Count of first choices. Candidate Duarte Farrajota Ramos has reached the
>   | threshold and is elected.
> ```
>
> **Winner is Duarte Farrajota Ramos.**

Comment: Congratulations to Duarte Farrajota Ramos

Comment: And thanks to everyone who participated!

Comment: My apologies everyone. I've finally got back to my computer to post the [official results](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2624/2019-community-moderator-election-results). Thankfully, there's not much risk of a discrepancy. Your new moderator will be getting a diamond in a moment.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [2019 Community Moderator Election Results](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2624/2019-community-moderator-election-results)

Comment: Thanks to anyone who voted, I'll be around if you have any questions.