# 2019 Community Moderator Election Results

Tags: discussion, election

Blender's [second moderator election](https://blender.stackexchange.com/election/2) has come to a close, the votes have been tallied and the new moderator is:

[image: Duarte Farrajota Ramos]

They'll be joining [the existing crew](https://blender.stackexchange.com/users?tab=moderators) shortly—please thank them for volunteering, and share your assistance and advice with them as they learn the ropes!

For details on how the voting played out, you can download the election results [here](https://blender.stackexchange.com/election/2), or [view a summary report online](https://www.opavote.com/results/5420301737263104/0).

Comment: Thanks to anyone who voted, I'll be around if you have any questions.

Comment: Congrats @DuarteFarajotaRamos

Comment: @DuarteFarrajotaRamos Congratulations mate! It was just natural choice for the community ;)

Comment: Thanks for the support :)

Comment: Congrats and good luck @DuarteFarajotaRamos.

Comment: Congratulations and good luck!